# Intel Advisor optimal flags and settings

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, vectorization, intel-parallel-studio, intel-advisor

I'm reading [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-advisor-tutorial-threading-linux-cplusplus) tutorial about code vectorization using Intel Advisor. In particular in this page they suggest to:

> Build the target sample application in release mode ... compiler options: -O2 -g

And following:

> To build your own applications to produce the most accurate and
>   complete Vectorization Advisor analysis results, build an optimized
>   binary in release mode using the following settings.

```
-g -O2 (or higher) -qopt-report=5 -vec -simd -qopenmp
```

Now, I have a couple of questions:

1. I thought that in release mode we didn't produce any debug information (which is produced in the "debug mode"), so no `-g` should be included
2. The weirdest thing is that in the Makefile given for the samples code (`vec_samples` in `/opt/intel/advisor_*/...`) uses only `-g -O2` why they don't include all the other options. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant entry point to fresh Intel Advisor tutorials is [Getting Started](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-advisor), where you can pick and choose appropriate sub-tutorials. **Vectorization Advisor sub-tutorial** for Linux can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-advisor-vectorization-linux). It precisely says that:

> -qopt-report=5 : necessary for version 15.0 of the Intel compiler; **unnecessary for version 16.0 and higher**

With regards to *-vec, -simd, -openmp*, the tutorial slightly confuses flags needed for proper Advisor functioning (-g, -O2, optionally -opt-report) vs. flags needed for "proper" Compiler functioning ( -vec, -simd and -openmp). The later ones are just flags controlling compiler's vector code generation, they have nothing to do with Advisor profiling capabilities so you may or may not use them.

---

To give you deeper understanding: there is an important feature in
   Advisor, which is called Intel Advisor Survey "Compiler Integration".
   This feature leverages the data relatively similar but not identical to opt-report.
   In order to make this feature working you need

1. Using **Intel** Coimpiler **14.x beta, 15.x, 16.x or 17.x**
2. **-g** (enable debug info) and **-O2** or higher (enable *some* optimization)
3. *Optional* (for Intel Compiler 15.x only) **-qopt-report5**

All other features in Intel Advisor work equally well regardless of Compiler version (item 1 above) or opt-report and versions (item 3 above) , but they all still require -g (part of option 2 above). -O2 is not needed for some features, but it is typically useless to deal with -O0 or -O1 compiled binaries when analyzing performance aspects.